# How to subclass a UILabel?

Tags: ios, methods, overriding, uilabel, subclassing

I made a simple subclass of UILABEL called CommaLabel that will eventually insert commas into a numeric string, like apple's calculator does. The compiler says my implementation is incomplete. Stupid question: what's missing? (I also don't understand what I have to do regarding memory management in here :-/) (i'm probably going to end up just implementing the processing code in the view controller but i just want to see how this would look anyway at this point...)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CommaLabel : UILabel

-(void)text:(NSString *)text;
-(void)setText:(NSString*)text;



@end

#import "CommaLabel.h"

@implementation CommaLabel



- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

-(NSString *) text{

    return super.text; 
}



-(void)setText:text
{

    super.text=text;
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to subclass `UILabel`? It sounds like you just need to add in a method in your viewController.

Comment: i was thinking of that approach, but i also like to be able to access my label's text directly from here or there... should i not do that?

Comment: also i just want a generic "rot 13" label class... or an "add commas to a number" class that i can just drop in... so wouldn't it be okay to make a self contained class that does something like that optionally?

Comment: @Dave: You can use `label.text` to access the text from anywhere that knows what `label` is. Even with subclassing, you will need to write functions to process your text and (possibly) to unprocess it. If you really want to subclass it, then I recommend you subclass `UIView` and stick a label on it.

Comment: i'm just experimenting here... i got a custom UILabel class and it only has (id) init, -(NSString *) text, and -(void)setText:text. it works basically but the compiler says incomplete implementation. what am i missing?

Comment: @Dave: Clearly without seeing the code I cannot help you. It sounds to me like you need to look at some tutorials online, and then post a question when you get stuck.

Comment: i've been looking at the tutorials... let me paste the code above... i'm sure you'll spot the bug in a second... this is just the skeleton of this to see if i have the syntax right.

Comment: i was planning on having a private ivar for the raw text without formatting, eventually, but i may just put that in the view controller now. i just liked the idea of it all being neatly self-contained in an object, is all.

Answer (score 1):

What's incomplete?

This, in the header:

```
-(void)text:(NSString *)text;
```

Doesn't match this, in the body:

```
-(NSString *) text{

    return super.text; 
}
```

Thus, the function specified as existing in the header is not in the body. That generates a compiler warning that the implementation is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would do well to start with a book or tutorial about Objective-C and iPhone programming. There is no need to write these setter and getter methods out explicitly instead of using `@property` and `@synthesize`. However, to address the immediate problems, your .h should read:

```
-(NSString*)text;
-(void)setText:(NSString*)newText;
```

and the .m should read:

```
-(NSString*)text{
    return text;
}

-(void)setText:(NSString*)newText {
    text = newText;
}
```

Usually it's a good idea to copy and paste the methods from the .h to the .m to ensure that they match exactly.

Comment: my left arm is leaning on the book, which wasn't helpful heh. I'm only writing these methods because i am going to override them in a moment. at least that's the plan.

Comment: @Dave: Make sure the `getter` method returns an output and that the `setter` method takes an input (and these should be the same type of object). You can declare properties, e.g. `rawText`, `processedText`, etc, that may make things easier for you. Then you will need setter and getter methds for both.

Comment: Thanks for giving me that, but when i typed what you gave me, the compiler didn't like `return text;`... it gave me "use of undeclared identifier "text"; did you mean "_text?" and "instance variable 'text' is private. :-/

Comment: yea that was my exact plan to have raw text and processed text... and always have the view controller only see the raw text and the user see the processed text in the label.